# Glide Cache management in Recyclerview with Grid layout

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-glide, android-gridlayout

I am trying to build a gallery for my app. Following some tutorials and stackoverflow, I finally managed to make the gallery. I am using Glide to set images, so no issue of memory crashing and all. The only problem is, when I fling, Images are not set into their views as fast as those views are being shown. Here is a [gif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByWB4JsSpOx6allmSTBGc0FjUTg/view?usp=sharing). So I get to see the placeholders or the background of the recyclerview while imageviews are being set. Depending on the fling speed, this may last for 500-1000ms. But that is sufficient to make the gallery look bad. This happens when I use fling to scroll up or down. To my knowledge, this is because glide freeing the images from it's cache. Is there any solution for it.
Here is my code.

activity_gallery:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_monuments"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GalleryActivity">



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how I am setting recyclerview:

```html
RecyclerView gridView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_gallery);
        gridView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
        gridView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        gridView.isDrawingCacheEnabled();
        gridView.addItemDecoration(new MarginDecoration(GalleryActivity.this, NUM_OF_COLUMNS, GRID_PADDING, true));
        gridView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        gridView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        gridView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
        GalleryAdapter galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(GalleryActivity.this, GalleryActivity.this, ImageNamesList, columnWidth);

        gridView.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
```

Here is how I am setting imageview in adapter:

```html
 viewHolder.galleryImage.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageWidth));
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(uri)
                .asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.monument)
                .centerCrop()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(viewHolder.galleryImage);
```

Please let me know of the possible solutions.

P.S: The gif is low frame rate and hence showing the slow fling which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

To solve cache management, i use a singleton store best practice. Realm for android is perfect it is NoSql and super fast, what i normally do is create a realm object, in the adapter check if the current url is in realm, if true dont pull new image else, pull and store.

Then when the main activity or fragment is ever being destroy just delete all from realm.